# Jquery object recursion and string match

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a Bible Search and I have a two questions. What I would like to do is allow someone to be able to type in a statement like,

> Genesis

or

> Genesis 4:20

or

> Gen 4:20

etc and then be able to locate that book or scripture but also distinguish it from other terms like...

> he was generous

So far I have built an object to check the name options...

```
var namesobj = {
    0 : {'name' : [] },
    1 : {'name' : ['Genesis','Gen','Gn'] },
    2 : {'name' : ['Exodus','Exod','Ex'] },
    3 : {'name' : ['Leviticus','Lev','Lv'] },
    4 : {'name' : ['Numbers','Num','Nm'] },
    // etc...
}
```

and I have created a function to search the string and check if the string matches one of the name possibilities.

```
var evaluateStr = function(str){
    if(allowGet === true){ // if there is not already a search in progress
        var nameFound = false; // escape var
        if(!nameFound)
        $.each(namesobj, function(bookid,values){ // iterate over the books
            if(!nameFound)
            $.each(values, function(attr, items){ // iterate over the options
                if(!nameFound)
                $.each(items, function(key, name){ // iterate over the actual names
                    if(str == name){ // if the string matches the name
                        alert("Yay");
                        nameFound = true; // force .each breaks
                        return false;
                    }else{
                        alert("Do something else");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

So how can I change this to see if the name value exists within the string instead of if the name is equal to the string?

And Secondarily

To me, my function seems like it's not very efficient but its all I know to do. It there possibly a better way to find if a book of the bible exists within the string?

Thank you in advance for any insight that you would be willing to share. I appreciate your time.

Comment: You could try with [Regular Expresions](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_regexp.asp)

Comment: I have designed a number of type ahead search functions and one Bible search engine. This is my insight: use a separate searching/matching function for the books and references vs. the text of the Bible verses. Ignore punctuation but otherwise require at least 5 chars (or both of two terms < 5 chars) to match when searching verse text. But allow partial (substring) matches and abbreviated (substrings w/o vowels) as well as exact matches to return true for the names of books of the Bible.

Comment: I understand that it is possible to use Regex, but how can I use it to test string against object values.

Comment: P.S. My Bible search code is 134 lines, but if I shared them with you, it would only make your search engine irrelevant. You should not mimic any other search engine. Creativity is the only way your search will offer any benefit compared to others. So the way for your search engine to be superior is for you to think of features/code on your own. Good luck!

Comment: @JosephMyers +1 +1 for the insights... Thank You. Although, I understand what you are saying, I am not looking to copy anyone's code, but to see some code would be beneficial to build my own. I have lots of ideas to create one of my own, I'm just not sure how to do it. I appreciate your candor, but I hope you will reconsider.

Comment: The biggest thing I need is to figure out is a regex to test string against value, and the most efficient and best way to get to my nested object value.

Comment: Paste this `<script src="http://ksathletics.com/2013/statetf/liveresults.js"></script>` into an HTML document, look at the results, and study the code. It's a script of mine for searching track and field events at the nation's largest T&F meet. The code for generating the data itself is proprietary, but you can certainly study the methods for searching the resulting data that has been generated. In your case, the data is already available, i.e., a plain text version of the Bible. The heart of the search code is here `http://ksathletics.com/2013/statetf/search.js`

Comment: You're essentially building a search engine for a very large string of text that's never going to change.  I'd start by building an engine that's going to catagorize my text fields by anything that's a string of characters between spaces and then sub catagorize that for common seperators (in this case a colon:) and create a database that holds all of those locations: Genesis exists 29 times in what locations, etc.  That makes your search very fast.  Obviously you can search the entire bible for the string "Genesis" every time but that's not terribly efficient.